# Does a magus deal damage as if using his off-hand with spell combat and spellstrike?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

The [magus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus)'s [spell combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Spell-Combat-Ex-) says, "This functions much like two-weapon fighting, but the off-hand weapon is a spell that is being cast."

When a magus delivers a touch spell as a free action using [spellstrike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Spellstrike-Su-) while employing a weapon, is his extra damage from his Strength bonus halved and his bonus damage from the feat [Power Attack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/power-attack-combat---final) as per an off-hand weapon?

Answer (score 2):

No, you're delivering the spell through your weapon that is in your main hand.  That language you're reading is to clarify that "you're using your offhand to cast a spell so you can't be holding anything else in it".  So you get none of the penalties you're specifically asking about.

If there's anything about the magus still confusing you I highly recommend that you read both [walter's guide to the magus](https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/d/1DB6sOfbAzFmKVPgcyLWipTVqvWFjfDSv6v_YiGQb5Yw/mobilebasic) and [this guide on the paizo rules forums](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpaizo.com%2Fthreads%2Frzs2nler%3FA-Guide-to-Touch-Spells-Spellstrike-and-Spell&ei=ERI1VeeUBM71oASixYCICw&usg=AFQjCNHmJK0pzVbDN8LRHKwwta3v5Kn6KA&sig2=sy7bgKeiUmA5kuCX9zoP3A&bvm=bv.91071109,d.cGU&cad=rja) (the latter specifically covers the intricacies of magus spell casting/fighting)

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that even if you *are* using two-weapon fighting, your main hand weapon still gets full Str (assuming it’s one-handed) and Power Attack; only the off-hand weapon gets reduced Power Attack (and Str for being light). The offhand casts the spell, but the main hand is wielding the weapon, and delivers the attack.

Comment: That's definitely important to note.  I thought I put something along those lines in my post but apparently left it out.